# how can i assign other values for coressponding value in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe column that contains a different numbers and each number has a different frequencies. there are 532 to unique value in column. and totally 59000 value are there.

```
0    135715
1    138775
2    134915
3    134335
4    134555
5    144995
6    136515
7    135185
8    145555
9    135245
...
```

How can i replace these values somehow corresponding to values in column that starts from 1 to 532. something like this.

```
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     5
6     5
7     6
8     7
9     1
10    1
11    4
...
```

I tried `np.where()` with `np.arange()` but it raise error.

Comment: Are you asking how to encode these values?

Comment: Welcome to SO! See my edit to correctly format your code blocks next time

Comment: As in like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619851/pandas-equivalent-of-statas-encode

Comment: It seems you need `df['new'] = pd.factorize(df.col)[0] + 1`